# Is adding the Debian repository to my apt source.list dangerous on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, linux

I'm trying to install a package from a Debian repository. I am trying to install manually with dpkg errors because of missing or incomplete dependencies. This got me wondering, is it a mistake to just add the Debian repository to my apt sources?

To be more specific I'm trying to install [Guake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake) (the console wrapper).

I'm trying to install Guake 0.4.1. This resolves an issue with transparency I'm having.

Comment: serverfault is for questions related to server/network administration.  This question seems like it is more about your desktop environment which makes it more suitable for superuser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a bad idea to install *binary* packages from Debian on Ubuntu. But it's a good idea to install packages from *source*! So here's how:

It's not that hard. Here's how to do it (instructions taken from my old note at http://www.asheesh.org/note/backporting-with-apt-src.html ):

Step 1: Make sure you have an appropriate deb-src line

Backporting is the process of taking source packages and compiling them on your Debian(-like) system. The easiest way to find Debian "source packages" is the same way you find Debian "binary packages": apt-get and its configuration.

Make sure you have this line in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

APT provides a command "apt-get source" that looks in these deb-src lines (rather than plain binary deb lines) and downloads *source* packages. In this tutorial, you'll use "apt-src" which is a convenient wrapper around "apt-get source".

Step 2

```
apt-get update
```

Step 3

```
sudo aptitude install apt-src
```

apt-src is a helper program that makes compiling source packages easy. It's not necessary, but it prevents you from having to type too many commands.

Step 4

```
 apt-src -bi install $package
```

If you wanted to install 'alpine', run this:

```
apt-src -bi install alpine
```

The "b" stands for "build", the "i" stands for "install the resulting package", and the word "install" means "download the source for alpine as found in a Debian source line from sources.list". apt-src will "install" the source into the current directory, make sure you have all the required packages to build the package (a process called "satisfying the build dependencies"), build it, and install the resulting .debs.

Comment: This is an awesome guide. +1 and accept if I get it to work. Quick question, I don't understand how the apt-src program knows to use the deb-src repo and not a karmic repo. Can you shed some light on that?

Comment: If you need to do this often and don't like having to go through all the steps, check this out: http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/scripts/backport.html

Comment: I updated the answer above to answer TheDeeno's question.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *good* idea per se -- even the build dependencies still expect an essentially Debian setup -- but it's definitely significantly less bad than installing a binary. +1

Comment: Shouldn't apt-src be run with sudo?

Comment: While useful, this particular answer misses one important step: adding the keys used to sign the repo. `for id in 8B48AD6246925553 7638D0442B90D010; do apt-key adv --recv-key $id --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80; done`. In my case the use of port :80 was necessary due to company firewall. It also appears to be quite important to install the recommendations along with `apt-src`, so if you have tweaked your defaults this would be another trap to fall into.

Comment: While the comment above addreses the issue, I still get `Err:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138`

Comment: Try for both the keys "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <Key as Displayed>"

Answer (score 1):

That is probably not the best way, as Debian and Ubuntu have different system paths, library versions and other dependencies. It might work though, but it will most probably fail in some way. You could get a better answer if you specified which package you are trying to install.

Conclusion: I would not recommend you doing it, other than for experimental use.

Comment: added package to my question

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

But: Guake is present in:

- [Ubuntu 9.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_9.10_.28Karmic_Koala.29) (Karmic Koala), http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/guake,
- [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx), http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/lucid/x11/guake.

You only have to enable the 'universe' repository.

Comment: It's in intrepid and jaunty, too: http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/x11/guake http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/x11/guake

Comment: hmm, I have guake installed 0.4.0 installed i'm trying to install 0.4.1 though. Is that in one of those repositories? Am I missing it? I updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There was mention of the command:

```
 add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

at http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast