# Consequences of upgrading libc6 on oneiric

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have a server running Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10, which I cannot upgrade.

I've followed instructions given here

https://serverfault.com/a/631664/246071

to upgrade bash. However, I noticed that these commands also upgrade libc6 among with other libraries. If I'm correct with my understanding, libc6 is a shared library used by many programs, including apache and mysql.

My question: what are the consequences of running the newest libc6 on an older system? Are there any incompatibilities?

Comment: The only way to fully know the answer to this is to test it in a lab.

Comment: And why can't you upgrade it? This has been out of support for _years_ and never should have been put in production anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it, your best bet would be to compile from source. You (normally) should even be able use the source from the latest (or older) Ubuntu release ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/da/lucid/bash ) and compile it on your old system.

But upgrade, seriously, what are you going to do with the next vulnerability?

Comment: So you think `shellshocker.net/fixbash` would be a better way?

Comment: You could, but then you're package information will no longer be correct because you updated this file outside apt/dpkg.